# construct a Item Market in andengine

Tags: android, android-layout, andengine, google-play

i'm developing game now.In my game,i want to construct a item market so that player can buy item from it.I'm looking for in forum but a can't find an example about that.The Market is composed by some of tabs.The tab is a scroll view contain some of item.The market can slice up when user touch on market Icon,and slice down when user finished his task.I dont' want to start new activity :( .in other way,I want to construct My market like the Shop of Bug Village game in Android Market https://market.android.com/details?id=c ... sYWdlIl0.I don't know how to contruct it,maybe Andengine can't support the unitily to program??? ,please help me :(